# Initialize an array of structs

Tags: c, struct

My code looks like this

```
struct {
    int valid;
    int pid;
    int heading;
    int speed;
} car;

struct car road[10];    //a road filled with cars
```

However, my compiler is complaining:

"incomplete struct/union/enum car: road"

What am I doing wrong? I looked at examples online and they show that this is how to initialize arrays of structs.

If it isn't obvious, I'm trying to make an array of car structs

Comment: Are you missing a typedef before `struct`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change :

```
struct {
    int valid;
    int pid;
    int heading;
    int speed;
} car;
```

which declares ***only one instance*** of an ***unnamed structure***, with the name `car`, to :

```
struct car{
    int valid;
    int pid;
    int heading;
    int speed;
};
```

which declares a new type `struct car`.The `struct`'s name needs to be next to the keyword `struct`.

---

You can also do :

```
typedef struct {
    int valid;
    int pid;
    int heading;
    int speed;
} car;
```

and then you only refer to this `struct` as `car`, not `struct car`.

See [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm) for more information on `structs` and their syntax.

Comment: Thanks this works! But.. I'm confused between the differences of declaring a struct with the name before and after the struct keyword. Do you know any tips on when to/differences on both?

Comment: @penu What do you mean *before* `struct` keyword?

Comment: @penu What you wrote defines a variable called `car` whose type is an unnamed struct. The `struct car { ... }` version defines a type called `struct car`. You can combine the two: `struct car { ... } my_car;` defines both a type `struct car` and a variable `my_car`.

Comment: Sorry, I mean before like as in how you typed it `struct car` and after like how I had it `struct {..} car;`

Comment: @penu in your example, 'car' becomes a variable of declared struct type, not the struct's name. That is the difference

Comment: Ahhhh! Thanks a lot, this makes much more sense now

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
struct {
  ...
} car;
```

declares a single instance of an anonymous structure, called `car`. You can view the `struct {... }` part as analogous with any other type name, except a new type is used. Since you don't give the structure a name, you can't create more than the `car` instance.

This might seem like a pointless thing to do, but it can be really useful when you want to group things together.

What you meant was this:

```
struct car {
 ...
};
```

which declares a new struct type, called `struct car`. You can use this name to refer to the declaration, and e.g. later create a bunch of instances like you did:

```
struct car road[10];
```

Comment: You could even combine the two declarations: `struct car { ... } road[10];` (probably not a good idea, though).

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 (without typedef):

```
struct car {
    int valid;
    int pid;
    int heading;
    int speed;
};

struct car road[10];
```

Option 2 (with typedef with unnamed struct):

```
typedef struct {
    int valid;
    int pid;
    int heading;
    int speed;
} car_t;

car_t road[10];
```

Option 3 (with typedef with named struct):

```
typedef struct car {
    int valid;
    int pid;
    int heading;
    int speed;
} car_t;

car_t road[10];
//or
struct car road[10];
```

---

The [Linux Coding Style](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/CodingStyle) states:

> It's a **mistake** to use typedef for structures...